# Quarkus 2.0 maven build is not creating uber-jar for AWS lambda

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, build, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 2.0 to build uber-jar to be used as AWS lambda.
Maven build script is as follows:

```
    <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>uber-jar</quarkus.package.type>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

`application.properties` also contains the `quarkus.package.type=uber-jar` config.

When I debug Maven build, I see that in the moment of making decision, `quarkus-maven-plugin` executes [the code](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/fcde34d5ee4d864a328c5c6caee5ee1db34d55e5/core/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/deployment/pkg/steps/JarResultBuildStep.java#L229):

```
@BuildStep
    public JarBuildItem buildRunnerJar(CurateOutcomeBuildItem curateOutcomeBuildItem, OutputTargetBuildItem outputTargetBuildItem, TransformedClassesBuildItem transformedClasses, ApplicationArchivesBuildItem applicationArchivesBuildItem, ApplicationInfoBuildItem applicationInfo, PackageConfig packageConfig, ClassLoadingConfig classLoadingConfig, List<GeneratedClassBuildItem> generatedClasses, List<GeneratedResourceBuildItem> generatedResources, List<UberJarRequiredBuildItem> uberJarRequired, List<UberJarMergedResourceBuildItem> uberJarMergedResourceBuildItems, List<UberJarIgnoredResourceBuildItem> uberJarIgnoredResourceBuildItems, List<LegacyJarRequiredBuildItem> legacyJarRequired, QuarkusBuildCloseablesBuildItem closeablesBuildItem, List<AdditionalApplicationArchiveBuildItem> additionalApplicationArchiveBuildItems, MainClassBuildItem mainClassBuildItem, Optional<AppCDSRequestedBuildItem> appCDS) throws Exception {
        if (appCDS.isPresent()) {
            this.handleAppCDSSupportFileGeneration(transformedClasses, generatedClasses, (AppCDSRequestedBuildItem)appCDS.get());
        }

        if (!uberJarRequired.isEmpty() && !legacyJarRequired.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Extensions with conflicting package types. One extension requires uber-jar another requires legacy format");
        } else if (legacyJarRequired.isEmpty() && (!uberJarRequired.isEmpty() || packageConfig.type.equalsIgnoreCase("uber-jar"))) {
            /* I want it get there, but it doesn't due to "legacyJarRequired" containing an item, ("packageConfig == uber-jar" as expected) */          

            return this.buildUberJar(curateOutcomeBuildItem, outputTargetBuildItem, transformedClasses, applicationArchivesBuildItem, packageConfig, applicationInfo, generatedClasses, generatedResources, uberJarMergedResourceBuildItems, uberJarIgnoredResourceBuildItems, mainClassBuildItem);
        } else {
            /* execution gets there because "legacyJarRequired" contains an item */
 
            return legacyJarRequired.isEmpty() && !packageConfig.isLegacyJar() && !packageConfig.type.equalsIgnoreCase("legacy") ? this.buildThinJar(curateOutcomeBuildItem, outputTargetBuildItem, transformedClasses, applicationArchivesBuildItem, packageConfig, classLoadingConfig, applicationInfo, generatedClasses, generatedResources, additionalApplicationArchiveBuildItems, mainClassBuildItem) : this.buildLegacyThinJar(curateOutcomeBuildItem, outputTargetBuildItem, transformedClasses, applicationArchivesBuildItem, packageConfig, applicationInfo, generatedClasses, generatedResources, mainClassBuildItem);
        }
    }
```

And item in the `legacyJarRequired` is added in [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/fcde34d5ee4d864a328c5c6caee5ee1db34d55e5/extensions/amazon-lambda/common-deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/amazon/lambda/deployment/FunctionZipProcessor.java#L36)

```
    @BuildStep(onlyIf = IsNormal.class, onlyIfNot = NativeBuild.class)
    public void requireLegacy(BuildProducer<LegacyJarRequiredBuildItem> required) {
        required.produce(new LegacyJarRequiredBuildItem());
    }
```

How can I avoid adding this element into build config to receive versioned `xxx-yyy-zzz-runner.jar` from my application build?

`function.zip` is built all right, but it's not an option for me, because I'd like to push the results of the build to maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to deploy an uber-jar to artifactory, for further deployment as AWS lambda. Finally I solved it with `build-helper-maven-plugin:attach-artifact` plugin. It attached `function.zip` to artifact in Nexus, so Jenkins was able to get the archive and deploy it to AWS.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>./target/function.zip</file>
                        <type>zip</type>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```